# Динамические данные с IoC контейнером

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container

Изучаю тему IoC и DI. Всё вроде понял зачем как и почему пока не дошел до IoC контейнера Unity. Непонятно следующее.
Объясняю на примере WPF MVVM:
У нас есть некие книги в базе данных, MainWindow c соответствующим ему MainWindowViewModel и DetailWindow с соответствующим DetailWindowViewModel, который принимает себе в конструктор книгу. Естественно и тот и другой ViewModel мы регистрируем в контейнере. На главном окне имеем поле ввода названия книги, заполнив которое производится поиск книги в БД и пользователю открывается окно с детальной информацией о выбранной книге.
Как это сделать? Ведь регистрируя тип данных в контейнере можно только что-нибудь захардкодить и не более. Не могу понять как это должно всё работать в жизни. Или вся эта концепция применяется только в каких-то отдельных случаях когда надо передать в качестве зависимости что-нибудь типа репозитория без конкретных данных?

Как вариант, конечно можно передавать детали о книге не через конструктор, а вызвав после создания DetailWindowViewModel какой-нибудь метод Init(IBook book), но на мой взгляд - это неправильно и небезопасно, т.к. без данных книги этот класс не имеет смысла, а конструктор как раз и нужен для того чтобы не забылись данные без которых класс не может работать.

Не поймите не правильно, я не критикую, я просто пытаюсь понять как это использовать и получается пока не очень.

Comment: Поясните подробней, что конкретно мешает передавать в конструктор ViewModel книгу прямо во время резолва?

Comment: Да, вы правы, я уже нашел эту возможность. Но только получается, что предварительно не посмотрев на конструктор ViewModel вы вообще никогда не узнаете, что нужно туда что-то передавать. При обычном методе создания студия сама подсказывает, что нужно конструктору, а тут тишина. Мне кажется - это сильно повышает вероятность ошибки.

Comment: конструктор де факто имеет очень высокую вероятность остаться без нужных ему данных из-за ошибки разработчика, который забыл передать книгу в Resolve

Comment: 1) Вы хотите динамически что то создавать и при этом находить ошибки при компиляции? Так не получится. 2) Программист не проверяет свой код? У вас нет юнит тестов?  3) Не нравится такой подход, вы можете делать свои фабрики и регистрировать

Comment: 1) Нет, хочу ошибку, что конструктору не дали параметр :)
2) Вопрос риторический. По возможности лучше исключить человеческий фактор, чем тратить время на его исправление.
3) понял. Спасибо

Comment: 1) Проверяйте параметры в конструкторе VM - там и создавайте исключение, если что то пошло не так

Comment: 2) Про человеческий фактор не понял. Просто пишете юнит тест на что надо и запускаете его перед пушем и на CI сервере - и все дела

Comment: да, вы правы. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Можно передавать параметры в UnityContainer.Resolve. При этом есть один минус: студия не подскажет если вы забудете передать параметры в конструктор через resolve. Избежать ошибок в этом месте можно проверяя в конструкторе корректность входных параметров и выдачей исключения, и применяя юнит-тесты

Answer (score -1):

Рассмотрим сферического коня в вакууме

```
class Foo {
    private Bar bar;

    public Foo() {
       this.bar = new Bar();
    }
}

class Bar {
    private string name = "bar";

    public getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

и вроде бы всё круто. Но вдруг мы захотим чтобы Foo.bar был другого класса? И почему Foo решил, что bar может быть только класса Bar?

Перепишем класс Foo и Bar

```
class Foo {
    private IBar bar;

    public Foo(IBar bar) {
       this.bar = bar;
    }
}

class Bar : IBar {
    private string name = "bar";

    public string getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}

interface IBar {
    string getName();
}
```

Вот. Теперь мы решаем какой bar будет у Foo, а не сам Foo. На вид инверсия управления. Плюсом мы теперь зависим от интерфейса, а не реализации.

Контейнер же нам позволяет не передавать вручную в конструктор Foo экземпляр IBar. Он такие дела разруливает за нас.

Comment: Поясните плиз, как ваш ответ коррелирует с заданным вопросом?